# How to remove ipv6

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I added `ipv6` to Raspbian (debian) on my Raspberry Pi using `modprobe`

I do not use it, and want to remove.

I tried `sudo modprobe -r ipv6` but get error `FATAL: Module ipv6 is in use.`

The only process I can find running is `ipv6_addrconf` which I can't seem to kill.

Comment: does it cause any problems? did you try to reboot?

Comment: I causes no problems, but uses a lot of memory (which the Pi doesn't have) and I am not using it.

Answer (score 1):

After a reboot your kernel should first start without any modules.
Modules are then loaded either explicitly via `/etc/modules` or automatically on detection of devices or manually via `modprobe`/`insmod`.

To avoid automatically loading you can [blacklist](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules#Blacklisting) those modules.

Therefore make sure it is not listed in `/etc/modules` and simply reboot your box. If your module is gone, fine, simply do not load it manually again. ;)

If you module is still there, it was loaded automatically. In this case blacklist it and do another reboot.

Comment: I tried `blacklist` with no effect `/proc/modules` shows `ipv6 351566 24 [permanent], Live 0xbf079000`

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I removed ipv6 from `/etc/modules`